# Matlab number of cols in excel file

Tags: excel, matlab

is there a command of Matlab to get the number of the written cols in excel file?

this is my excel file:
[image]

this is my code:

```
e = actxserver ('Excel.Application'); %# open Activex server
filename = fullfile(pwd,'example2.xlsx'); %# full path required
ewb = e.Workbooks.Open(filename); %# open the file
esh = ewb.ActiveSheet;
```

And I tried:

```
intCol = Range('IV1').End(xlLeft).Col;
```

thank you :]

Comment: I'm assuming you went intCol = esh.Range('IV1').End(xlLeft).Col; ? If that didn't work, it could be because your spread sheet is reading right to left. Maybe you should try intCol = esh.Range('IV1').End(xlRight).Col; ?

Comment: Also are you getting an error, or just the incorrect result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about:

```
[num, txt, raw] = xlsread('example2.xlsx');
intCol = size(raw, 2);
```

Comment: thank you, I tried anyway what you suggested, and I got an error message:
??? Error using ==> subsindex
Function 'subsindex' is not defined for values of class 'cell'.

Error in ==> test9 at 298
    num_cols = size(raw, 2)

but I prefer a command line that will be similar to how I found the rows:

     sheetObj = e.Worksheets.get('Item', 'Sheet1');
     num_rows = sheetObj.Range('A1').End('xlDown').Row;

Comment: ??? Error using ==> subsindex Function 'subsindex' is not defined for values of class 'cell'. Error in ==> test9 at 298     num_cols = size(raw, 2)

Comment: weird - it works for me. I can go size(CELL_MATRIX, 2), what version of matlab are you running. Maybe the syntax has changed?

Comment: Silly question, but do you by any chance have a variable named size in your workspace? Because that gives me the same error. Try 'clear size' before calling size. If it fixes the error, call your variable something other than size and this should work for you.

Comment: Hi again, I had a variable that is called 'size', so I changed its name to: "size_pixels'. now, I don't have a variable of size, but it doesn't work: [num, txt, raw] = xlsread('example2.xlsx');
intCol = size(raw, 2);
(the error is the same error)

I used this line: [num, txt, raw] = xlsread('example2.xlsx'); also in the first line of the code.
there is a chance that I have to reset something?

I tried  intCol = esh.Range('IV1').End(xlRight).Col; and the other option, but it doesn't work :/

thank you for your help..

Comment: just make sure you have deleted the variable called size. type 'clear size' in the command line and make sure you aren't recreating it anywhere. That is the only possible source of that error that I can think of. Try closing and reopening matlab and running ONLY the two lines in this answer and nothing else and see if the error is still there.